# Error while accessing resource: Please enter values for sector

Tags: postman, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitetalk

I would like to know how to create the correct body for creating a customer record. I am using the Postman examples that I downloaded from Netsuite and I'm accessing `/record/v1/customer` as POST, but I keep getting this Sector and Subsidiary error. By the way, I don't have access to the Netsuite dashboard for now. I am still waiting
for my company to give me access. Would really appreciate the help, or even just pointing me to the right direction. Thanks a lot!

**[image: strong text]**

Answer (score 2):

Sector is not a NetSuite standard field name. It could either be a custom entity field or a standard field that was renamed to Sector. You will have to get the correct ID for this field from your account.

Answer (score 1):

Try a get request to:
`/record/v1/customer`

That will list all the customers currently in your account, by ID (hopefully there are some).

Pick one of those IDs (eg 99) and make a get request to:
`/record/v1/customer/99`

and that will return the customer record in JSON. Have a look for something that looks like `sector` in there.

Comment: Silas: I have posted a similar question about taxItem instead of sector.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77514585/unable-to-set-taxcode-while-creating-updating-a-customer-record-using-netsuite-r
When I pulled the Customer record, taxItem wasn't present in response however when I pulled it by adding ?fields=taxItem in the URL, taxItem was returned with the value and same format. Would you know how to resolve the error?