# Error while accessing a resource. Please enter value(s) for: Tax Item

Tags: netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

API URL: https://<NETSUITE_ID>.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer/eid:123

Method: PUT

Payload:

```
{
  "email": "ab.test+sb@xyz.com",
  "companyName": "Test EiO Trigger V2",
  "subsidiary": {
    "id": "29"
  },
  "taxItem": {
      "id": "808"
  }
}
```

I am getting the following response with error while trying to upsert a Customer record using the above NetSuite REST API :-

```
{
    "type": "https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-15.5.1",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "o:errorDetails": [
        {
            "detail": "Error while accessing a resource. Please enter value(s) for: Tax Item.",
            "o:errorCode": "USER_ERROR"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have verified that the tax code internal id value exists. Not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: Did you try passing the id as a number instead of string? e.g. `"taxItem": {
      "id": 808
  }`, or trying to eliminate the curly brackets `"taxItem": "id": "808"`...

Comment: Yes, tried both and received the same error.

Comment: In the documentation (https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2023_2/script/record/customer.html) they refer to the customer fields in lower case letters -included the `taxitem`. I'm not totally sure of this but likely you need to use `taxitem` instead of `taxItem`.

Comment: I have tried with lowercase as well. Unfortunately it didn't change the error.

Comment: Mmmm, please keep an eye on the documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_1545142173.html#subsect_161788160649. I saw that you can use PATCH instead of PUT also. Looking at this example of how to use this kind of endpoint could help you on this issue.

Comment: No, that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the following doc, REST Webservices is no longer supporting Legacy Tax features.
https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/99106/loc/en_us

Consider using Restlet instead of Rest API for this.

Comment: Thank you for feeding me back @abitgcp01. Please, note that the link you shared is linked to your Netsuite account or to another link which is not publicly available. I just found it in Netsuite public docs at https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/chapter_1558962745.html#Web-Services-Supported-Records. It refers that "... To work with taxation through REST web services, [we] must have the SuiteTax feature enabled. For more information about using SuiteTax."